# Rename value within query

Tags: mysql, database, javafx, javafx-8, pie-chart

I have a problem with renaming a specific value in a column in mySQL Database. At first i thought i could just use 'AS' to rename, but i'm actually trying to rename a value in a column. My column is named FoundLost. In this column I Store values '0' and '1'. '0' is Found and '1' is Lost.

The reason I need to rename this values is because I use the data from this database to create a pieChart. with the function .getName it gives the names '0' and '1'.

I was hoping someone could help me out!

The class with the query is the code below:

```
public static ObservableList getPChartFoundLost() {
    String query = "SELECT FoundLost, concat(round(count(FoundLost) *100 / (SELECT count(FoundLost) FROM Luggage))) AS percent FROM Luggage GROUP BY FoundLost";

    ObservableList FoundLost = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Connection connection = DatabaseUtils.connect();

    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                FoundLost.add(new PieChart.Data(resultSet.getString("FoundLost"), resultSet.getInt("percent")));
            }

            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
        }
        DatabaseUtils.disconnect(connection);
    }

    return FoundLost;
}
```

Controller:

```
    public void clickPChartFoundLost(ActionEvent event) {

    //PieChart
    ObservableList FoundLost = StatisticsUtils.getPChartFoundLost();

    pieChart.setVisible(true);
    pieChart.setData(FoundLost);
    pieChart.setTitle("Found and Lost luggage");

    for (final PieChart.Data data : pieChart.getData()) {
        data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {

                //Label vullen met data van Observable list uit Database
                pieChartValueLable.setText(String.valueOf(data.getName()) + ": "
                        + String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, try this as your first column instead of just `FoundLost`. It translates your `0` and `1` values to meaningful strings for your chart. The rest of your query can stay the same.

```
IF(FoundLost = 0,'Found','Lost') AS FoundLost
```